# Grep for a pattern in line

Tags: grep, sed, regex

How can i grep for a specific pattern of numbers like

```
1000010000000
```

in a whole file - the line has to have thes numbers at the beginning not somewhere else...

Comment: In only one file and always the same pattern?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous about the variability of the sequence of numbers.  A sample of lines from your file (some lines that qualify and some that do not) which represent any fringe cases would go a long way to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

For a search with that exact string `1000010000000` at the beginning of the line, a

```
grep "^1000010000000"
```

is ok.

---

More flexible is a pattern like this (as example):

```
grep -P "^1[0]{4,4}1[0]{7,7}" <your_file>
```

Explanation:

- `^1[0]{4,4}1[0]{7,7}`

  [image: Regular expression visualization]

  - `^` assert position at start of the string
  - `1` matches the character 1 literally
  - `[0]{4,4}` match a single character present in the list below

    - Quantifier: `{4,4}` Exactly 4 times
    - `0` the literal character `0`
  - `1` matches the character 1 literally
  - `[0]{7,7}` match a single character present in the list below

    - Quantifier: `{7,7}` Exactly 7 times
    - `0` the literal character `0`

Comment: This s[e]{2,2}ms n[e]{2,2}dlessly complex.

Comment: Why are people down-voting this answer?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because this answer is promoting a needlessly verbose quantifier syntax as well as unnecessarily using character classes to list a single character -- as thomas cleverly insinuated.

Answer (score 1):

`grep '^1000010000000' filename`

The caret means beginning of line.

Edit:
Just found a helpful tutorial for this sort of thing [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/regular-expressions-in-grep-command/).

Comment: OP wrote " ... a specific pattern of numbers like ... "

Comment: This is the simplest regex that would find that specific pattern of numbers at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
sed -n '/^1000010000000/p' file
```

Explanation

The `-n` means suppress normal output, so we only print the lines we want.

The `/^1000010000000/` means match line with the pattern at the beginning of the line. The `^` is an anchor meaning the start of a line.

The `p` prints out the matched line.

Comment: OP wrote " ... a specific pattern of numbers like ... "